# How can a float64 have a hyphen in it?

Tags: python, pandas

Noob here.
I am trying to work with this dataset in python:
https://r2.datahub.io/clt98khox0004ia08zwe4vaqt/master/raw/data/co2-mm-gl.csv

I have imported the data using pandas read_csv.
I then took a look at the format of each column using dtypes and saw that the first column 'Date' was a float64,
which is weird, because the values in this column are formatted as year-month, like "1979-01".
How can a float64 type have a hyphen like that?
Thanks for any insights.

I first tried manipulating the "Date" column with:

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[:4]
```

and received the error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`
I see that this is because it is a float64. But how can it be a float64?

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Looking at the CSV file it has in header fewer column names as actual data columns.

Comment: The first column is clearly a string. `pandas read_csv` is making a mistake when it imports the data

Comment: Maybe it's treating `1979-01` as a subtraction expression, i.e. "1979 minus one"?

Comment: Remember to specify the `dtype` argument when using `pandas.read_csv` to prevent pandas from guessing and getting things wrong.

Comment: @John No, Pandas wouldn't evaluate the input data as an expression

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. If e-motta's answer is right (I haven't looked at the CSV myself), it seems like you could have caught the mistake by just printing the dataframe. Please, in the future, try that first. More generally, examine the problem yourself and think critically about what could be wrong. For specifics see [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). If you want more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You CSV file has only 4 headers, but 6 columns:

```
Date,Decimal Date,Average,Trend
1979-01,1979.042,336.56,0.11,335.92,0.09
1979-02,1979.125,337.29,0.09,336.25,0.10
...
```

When you import it, Pandas leaves the first two columns without a name:

```
                    Date  Decimal Date  Average  Trend
1979-01 1979.042  336.56          0.11   335.92   0.09
1979-02 1979.125  337.29          0.09   336.25   0.10
...
```

---

You can edit the CSV to add two more column names for the last 2 columns:

```
Date,Decimal Date,Average,Trend,Value1,Value2
1979-01,1979.042,336.56,0.11,335.92,0.09
1979-02,1979.125,337.29,0.09,336.25,0.10
...
```

Which will then be imported as:

```
      Date  Decimal Date  Average  Trend  Value1  Value2
0  1979-01      1979.042   336.56   0.11  335.92    0.09
1  1979-02      1979.125   337.29   0.09  336.25    0.10
...
```

Comment: Thank you all! As you point out there were not enough header values in that CSV. It seems that in that case, read_csv fills in the headers from right to left, so when I tried to manipulate column 1 with 'df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[:4]', it thought I was talking about column 3 and correctly informed me that it was not a string.

Comment: I solved it with the following code:

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(urlwithcsv, header=0, names=['Date', 'Decimal Date', 'Average', 'Trend','Value1','Value2'])